# Do XMLHttpRequests work in internet explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, activex

Refer to title question.  I am very new to javascript and used it while making an html page for work on my laptop that works perfectly fine with Internet Explorer 8, but it does not work on anyone's computer that has installed IE11.  As we are all supposed to upgrade to IE11 (nobody told me until this issue came up), I need to figure out why this works in IE8 and not IE11.  I am guessing that the XMLHttpRequests are the issue.  Basically I am using the xmlhttprequests to check if some files exist before posting them to the html page.

I'm in the process of requesting and getting approved to install IE11, but was hoping someone could clarify if I am correct that XMLHttpRequests do not work in IE11 and could possibly suggest any alternatives?

Edit:
Well magic stuff occurred and now its working.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is an Internet-wide standard. It would be wrong and very surprising if any modern browser didn't implement it. I think your guess is wrong.

Comment: If you want to know which browsers support particular features, go to www.caniuse.com.

Comment: How about posting your java script so we can look at it and try and figure out why it doesn't work in IE 11?

Comment: caniuse.com says that IE11 has partial support for XMLHttpRequest advanced features. The notes say that it's missing support for `json` as `responseType`. It doesn't even have a section for basic support of XMLHttpRequest, presumably because it's supported almost everywhere.

Comment: your routine might be sniffing for "MSIE" to fork support (instead of using object detection), which would trigger on IE11, and thus it would try to use ActiveX controls that were remove in IE11...

Comment: Hey, I was testing my website on every browser I can think of, and I used IE 11. My Page (Heavily reliant on XHR) did not work. I used a button click tied to an event listener which fires an XHR. works in chrome, beaker, opera, edge, firefox, safari, opera lite, tor, firefox mobile and IE 7 to 10 and chrome mobile. All except IE11.

Comment: Use IE11 debugging, it could be a myriad of things...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long Answer: Internet Explorer has supported XHR (XMLHTTPResponse) since IE 7. Since then it has improved considerably. There are many things that can stop code from working. Have you tried running your code in IE 11 and then checking the debug console to see what it says?

Unfortunately, since you did not post any code for us to examine; we can't really do much for you except answer your very specific and easily searchable question.

Recommendation: Use jQuery to do AJAX requests instead and examine the debug console for errors.

Comment: My apologies if this is not what you wanted to hear, but it's a honest and correct answer to the question. I see no reason for the down vote. Constructive thinking can be taught in many ways.